# SQL SSRS Report Builder - cannot see views only tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS Report Builder with SQL 2005 and I am trying to build some reports from my data sources.

However when I bring up the data source entities it is only showing tables not views which is what I want to use to make the coding neater and easy to use.

Am I missing something?  Can anyone advise a way to get the views to be shown up in the Entities options?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Report Builder 2005 shows whatever entities are defined in a model. How the model was created - in Model Designer, or via Generate Model in Report Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the note in the following posting, if you created your model using Report manager it does not show views. You need to use Development studio.
See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ac2cb68f-84d9-4bcb-86c1-ea161082c2e9)